# Could not create connection to database server, Android Studio

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, database-connection

So this is my first time with Android studio,I am trying to connect mysql database using jdbc. Here is my Database connection Class:

```
import android.util.Log;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class conBD {


    public static Connection getconnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/achat","root","");

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("conbdtry", e.getMessage());

        }

        return con;

    }

}
```

And "getconnection" should be executed when clicking a button in th main activity. But i don't know why i'm keep getting the exception msg of "Could not create connection to database server".

I tried the same code in netbeans and it's working as it should, it inserts, selects and deletes from my database, I also tried changing the host to my ip adress but always same problem. can anyone help me please!

Comment: and what is the complete error message you are getting

Comment: Do you truly have mysql installed on android?

Comment: this is the whole message, it's from the catch exception.

Comment: yes, i'm working with xampp

Comment: Apologies if I am barking up the wrong tree, but I suspect _"yes, i'm working with xampp"_ actually means "no, xampp is running on my host PC". `localhost` is referring to the emulator (or testing device), not the host PC.